# Number of orderings of 4 objects in 3 slots (with replacement)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider $i, s_1, s_2$ and $r$ as four objects. What is all possible orderings of these objects in 3 slots?

Comment: For the first position you have four possibilities, namely $s_1$, $s_2$, $i$, $r$. After you choose one, say $i$, you have three possibilities for the second position, and so on. This in total $24$ such orderings

Comment: This if you don't allow repetition of course. Otherwise $4^3$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $4^3 = 64$ since there are 4 choices for each element.

Comment: Aha yes. i was being stupid..